# Symantec Scan Engine .NET API Error

Tags: virus-scanning, symantec

I am currently using Symantec Scan engine .NET api for anti virus scanning. I am getting this error "ERR_INITIALIZING_STREAM_REQUEST" - Problem encountered while initializing a stream request to Symantec Scan Engine.  But not much details are present. Just object reference error is present in the exception part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer. 
The problem was with Windows firewall. 
Solution:
Go the server (Win 2008R2 in my case.).
Access Windows Firewall with advanced security.
In the InBound Rule, create a new rule for the port(1344 in my case) through which you are gonna access the symantec scan engine
Similarly create an OutBound Rule for the same port.
Run the application... Viola.....  it was working!!!!!